# How to make akinator command in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making my bot, I wanted to add a command on which when I call it as .tell it will send me questions and enter `n` or `y`. But I am stuck in the code, the following code is not running.WHat's the problem with this anyone pls help.This is the code:

```py
import akinator
@client.command()
async def tell(ctx):
    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel and msg.content.lower() in ["y", "n"]
    msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    try:
        aki = akinator.Akinator()
        q = aki.start_game()
        while await ctx.send(aki.progression <= 80):
            if msg.content.lower() == "b":
                try:
                    await ctx.send(aki.back())
                except akinator.CantGoBackAnyFurther:
                    pass
            else:
                await ctx.send(aki.answer(msg))
        aki.win()
        correct = await ctx.send(await client.wait_for(f"It's {aki.first_guess['name']} ({aki.first_guess['description']})! Was I correct?\n{aki.first_guess['absolute_picture_path']}\n\t", check=check))
        if correct.lower() == "yes" or correct.lower() == "y":
            await ctx.send("Yay\n")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Oof\n")
    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send(e)
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65904594/edit) your question and fix the formatting (put the code in a codeblock), take a look at how your question currently looks, do you think we can read that?

Comment: your problem's source is probably the `while await ctx.send(aki.progression <= 80)` line you wrote

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński But i  think it is correct and readable

Comment: @Bharat because someone else edited the question for you. Your question before looked like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65904594/1)

Answer (score 0):

````py
@bot.command(aliases=["aki"])
async def akinator(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Akinator is here to guess!")
    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel and msg.content.lower() in ["y", "n","p","b"]
    try:
        aki = ak.Akinator()
        q = aki.start_game()
        while aki.progression <= 80:
            await ctx.send(q)
            await ctx.send("Your answer:(y/n/p/b)")
            msg = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
            if msg.content.lower() == "b":
                try:
                    q=aki.back()
                except ak.CantGoBackAnyFurther:
                    await ctx.send(e)
                    continue
            else:
                try:
                    q = aki.answer(msg.content.lower())
                except ak.InvalidAnswerError as e:
                    await ctx.send(e)
                    continue
        aki.win()
        await ctx.send(f"It's {aki.first_guess['name']} ({aki.first_guess['description']})! Was I correct?(y/n)\n{aki.first_guess['absolute_picture_path']}\n\t")
        correct = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
        if correct.content.lower() == "y":
            await ctx.send("Yay\n")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Oof\n")
    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send(e)```
````

Comment: Hi. Please consider adding an explanation of your code, highlighting relevant parts, so your answer would be more useful to others who look for help.

Comment: @Bharat You are using "client" as a variable and i used "bot".Just change all "bot" words to "client". And if the error persists please tell me what error you are getting.Maybe then i can help.

Comment: @Fabio Mendes Soares Sorry man i am new to this platform will try to edit the answer when i am free.

Comment: @Mastermindsap I have correct all those variable , it is not giving any errors but not giving question to ask

Comment: @Bharat it should give.Please check my code here https://github.com/Mastermind-sap/joker/blob/main/joker.py I have updated it also with some embeds and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

For importing Akinator(), it's not `akinator` but `akinator.async_aki`.

```
from akinator.async_aki import Akinator
```

Or, in your code, replace `aki = akinator.Akinator()` with `aki = akinator.async_aki.Akinator()`